# asp.net core docker-compose refresh on code changes

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I've read [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount) that I can get possibility not to run `docker-compose build` every time code changes by adding volumes sections to docker-compose.yml. But I can't achieve this feature in my ASP.NET Core application.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["dockercompose/dockercompose.csproj", "dockercompose/"]
RUN dotnet restore "dockercompose/dockercompose.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/dockercompose"
RUN dotnet build "dockercompose.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "dockercompose.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dockercompose.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockercompose:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}dockercompose
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockercompose/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "9000:80"
    volumes:
     - .:/src/dockercompose
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `dotnet watch run` for that. However that means you need to use the SDK image (microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk) not the runtime only image (microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime).

I just use two Docker files and have two services defined in the docker-compose.yml. One uses the dockerfile with the runtime image (for deployment), the other one with the SDK image (for development).

The development dockerfile could look something like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
# Use native linux file polling for better performance
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER 1
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT dotnet watch run --urls=http://+:5000
```

You might have to chnage the path according to your project and how you map it in your docker-compose.yml, but this is more or less it.

Comment: Additionally, you might find this post useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/9cyl6a/debugging_dotnet_watch_processes_inside_of_a/ . It describes how to set up debugging with docker, aspnet-core and vscode on linux

Comment: if I use this dockerfile, it tells me Could not find a MSBuild project file in '/app'. Specify which project to use with the --project option . I understand that I have to write ENTRYPOINT dotnet watch -p somepath run --urls=http://+:5000 but I don't know which path to specify.

Comment: Try using your volumes path: `/src/dockercompose` instead of `/app`.

Comment: It's running with reload when I build an image and run it, but if I do that via docker-compose up it gives me Error(s) finding watch items project file 'docker-compose.dcproj'

Comment: Does the `Directory.Build.props` file that you referenced on reddit need to be created for every project in case our solution has multiple projects? Or does it only need to be inside the main project that acts as the startup (i.e. the WebAPI / WebApp project)? Thanks