# Is ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI possible to hot apply code changes to deployed container in Visual Studio 2019 at development?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, containers, hot-reload

VS able to let us update codes while developing our website in debug mode. I used to pause execution somewhere by breakpoints and then update my code and save it in order to see my updated codes executed results immediately. However, seems this is not how the way docker with VS working.

Whenever I update my codes when execution paused, I save the source file and click "apply code changes" and I found nothing was changed.

May I know if it is possible to get it updated immediately instead of restarting and deploying it every time?

p.s. have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571446/asp-net-core-docker-compose-refresh-on-code-changes) solution but no luck